# How do I round to the nearest 0.5 in RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have to round values in my RDLC expression.

If the decimal part is greater than .50 I need to add 1 to the value. If the decimal part is less than .50 I need only the value.

Examples:

- If value is 14.51 it must return 15.
- If value is 14.32 it must return 14.

Comment: Just use .net Math.Round method.

Comment: thanks ..that worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While designing RDLC, in the expression editor, select common functions > Math > Round function

Answer (score 1):

```
double yourNumber= 14.42;    
Math.Round(yourNumber, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```